# How to import makeStyles from Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI version 5.2.7. When I import makeStyles from `@mui/materials/styles`, I am getting the following error -

`Uncaught Error: MUI: makeStyles is no longer exported from @mui/material/styles. You have to import it from @mui/styles. See https://mui.com/r/migration-v4/#material-ui-core-styles for more details.`

It also says that `@mui/styles` is deprecated in Material UI version 5. So I am confused about how I can import makeStyles. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you can see in [documentation](https://mui.com/styles/basics/), using makeStyles is deprecated now in Material UI as a concept, because they do not want to use JSS anymore, instead they suggest using `emotion/react` library or `styled components`.

Answer (score 9):

instead of makeStyles you can just create object with styles ( style={your styles} ) inside functional component and then use sx property(  sx={style} ) on MUI component inside that functional component.

Comment: So what are the types are gonna be if I am using TypeScript?

Answer (score 3):

I came across this thread. I know this is a bit old but you can still use `makeStyles` in Material UI v5 using this import (will be deprecated):

`import makeStyles from '@mui/styles/makeStyles';`

This is automatically updated if you run their codemod from their documentation migrating from V4 to V5:
[Material UI Codemod](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/#run-codemods)

Answer (score 3):

The successor of jss is [tss-react](https://www.tss-react.dev/):

> ### makeStyles is dead  long live makeStyles!
>
> The great hook based CSS-in-JS API now with state of the art TypeScript support

From the [Readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tss-react):

> 'tss-react' is intended to be the replacement for @material-ui v4 makeStyles and 'react-jss'.

It's option #2 in the [guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migrating-from-jss/#2-use-tss-react) on Migrating from JSS. Developed and maintained independently by [Joseph Garrone](https://github.com/garronej).

There's also an automated [codemod](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-codemod/README.md#jss-to-tss-react) available for helping you with switching:

```
npx @mui/codemod v5.0.0/jss-to-styled <path>
```