# getting a problem while using makestyles and creating a const variable in app.js or styles.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am currently learning material UI and the problem is

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/material/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #333, #999)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 15,
    color: 'white',
    padding: '0 30px'
  }
})
```

I am in the process of creating a button and giving them styles.
whenever I create this const variable everything on the page vanishes, and when I delete them everything gets restored. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: What error do you gen in the console?

Comment: MUI: makeStyles is no longer exported from @mui/material/styles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import makeStyles from mui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625797/how-to-import-makestyles-from-mui)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it:

npm install @mui/styles

Then import it with:

import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'

Comment: i tried this command but i am getting  error

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: materialui@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!