# How to configure VSCode autoimport with multiple sources for the same name?

Tags: typescript, import, material-ui, configuration, ambiguous

I've entered the symbol `makeStyles` with multiple possible import sources into VSCode. When I trigger "Add all missing imports" via Quick Fix or by having `"editor.codeActionsOnSave": { "source.addMissingImports": true }` in the settings.json, it adds the wrong import

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/material";
```

instead of the right import

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
```

Is there any way to configure the correct import source? The most convenient one would be for VSCode to look at the other files and see which import sources are used for which symbols. Or some kind of map from symbol name to import source. Is this possible?

Comment: I guess it has to do with the [deprecation of @mui/styles](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/) because it is not even shown as suggestion on  `Ctrl` + `Space` [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-features)/[editor.action.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_rich-languages-editing)[triggerSuggest](/a/53015835).

Comment: *"@mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18."* Wow, now that's a reason not to use it right there.

Comment: Sure, only until we switch to the new version and probably [tss-react](https://www.tss-react.dev/)! ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625797/how-to-import-makestyles-from-material-ui/73906164#73906164))